# Using RapidMiner to train a model from multiple files

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-regression, rapidminer

I am working on some project and need to train my model using data files. The problem is that the size of data file that is to be used for training of model is 10 gigs. So, I am not able to import the data at once. 
Alternative is to trim the data and use only 5% of the training data. But I might loose some information.
My question is "Is it possible to train the model by splitting the file into multiple files ?"

Comment: Maybe you should post this question in the **rapidminer forums**, not on a *programming* website. Because it is about using the program rapidminer, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `Update Model` operator to update a previously created model with new example set data. Not all model operators can be used this way, Naive Bayes and k-NN do work as does Weka's W-IBk.

It would be possible to create a process within RapidMiner to split files into smaller pieces, read them  one by one and create a model from these.